# my query works with timestamp but gives an error with datetime

Tags: datetime, eloquent, timestamp, php-carbon, laravel-5.8

I have a mysql table with the following columns

name | dateone | mail | created_at

the "dateone" field is  date type

the "created_at" field is  timestamp type

in my controller I have a method to group the result by date

```
$users = Post :: orderBy ('dateone') -> get () -> groupBy (function ($ item) {

 return $ item-> created_at-> format ('Y-m-d');
```

it works, **but**, when I replace

return $ item-> **created_at**-> format ('Y-m-d');

by

return $ item-> **dateone**-> format ('Y-m-d');

I have the following error:

*Call to a member function format() on string*

is there a solution through Carbon or other to solve my problem ?

thank for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default **created_at** and **updated_at** are in the [Carbon Instance](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). You can use dateone as created_at by parsing it to the carbon instance.

```
$convertedDateOne = null;
if(!empty($item->dateone)){
    $convertedDateOne = Carbon::parse($item)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

If you want the dateone to be the instance of Carbon every time, you can [cast in the datetime format](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) in the model.

*Supposing the model name is Item.php*

```
class Item extends Model{
   protected $dates = ['dateone'];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot lizeshakya for your help.  ` protected $dates`  in the model  works. The other solution works well too. Carbon is a really powerful class. Thank you again for your help